# Using one jquery function to calculate hours worked for multiple input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to build a website based "spreadsheet" which will be used to calculate hours/labor used for a group of "employees". I was able to figure out how to calculate hours for ONE of the "employees", but I am not able to figure out how to use the same formula/function for the other "employees". [This jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dragoonman/arcxdff2/) has the basic structure of what I have been able to put together so far.

```
<form>
  <table id="actual" cellspacing="0px">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Start Time</th>
      <th>End Time</th>
      <th>
        Total Time
      <br/> Worked
    </th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Greg Weiland</th>
  <td>
    <input class="Time1" type="time">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input class="Time2" type="time">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input class="Hours">
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Alicia Hawly</th>
  <td>
    <input class="Time1" type="time">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input class="Time2" type="time">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input class="Hours">
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Charlen Connoly</th>
  <td>
    <input type="time">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="time">
  </td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Dakota Giles</th>
  <td>
    <input type="time">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="time">
  </td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Donovan Cole</th>
  <td>
    <input type="time">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="time">
  </td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Robert Hill</th>
  <td>
    <input type="time">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="time">
  </td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Douglas Spirs</th>
  <td>

$(function() {
  function calculate() {
   var time1 = $(".Time1").val().split(':'),
     time2 = $(".Time2").val().split(':');
   var hours1 = parseInt(time1[0], 10),
     hours2 = parseInt(time2[0], 10),
     mins1 = parseInt(time1[1], 10),
     mins2 = parseInt(time2[1], 10);
   var hours = hours2 - hours1,
     mins = 0;
   if (hours < 0) hours = 24 + hours;
   if (mins2 >= mins1) {
     mins = mins2 - mins1;
   } else {
     mins = (mins2 + 60) - mins1;
     hours--;
   }
   mins = mins / 60; // take percentage in 60
   hours += mins;
   hours = hours.toFixed(2);
   $(".Hours").val(hours);
 }
 $(".Time1,.Time2").change(calculate);
 calculate();
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am unsure of how to make the rest of the employees calculate time correctly.

Please note that I do not care if the calculation is done through a single button or if it is accomplished as a result of changing the value of the "cells".

Comment: You can use JQuery.each() for each tr in your table. You will need more JavaScript code to accomplish that.

Comment: Your table will need some changes and I would put all the names in an array and add rows to the table based in each user. With that in mind, you can create input fields for each specific user where they can have a unique id. With the class will be a little bit to messy.

Comment: I would suggest using "starttime" and "endtime" as a class rather than "Time1" "Time2" but that is minor

Comment: Your form is likely to submit prior to calculation so I would suggest change to the button `<button id="worked" type="button">Worked</button>` and then use `$('#worked').on('click',calculate);` or `$('#worked').on('click',function(){calculate(); $('form').submit();});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a different method that does what you ask with much less code. Also, I went ahead and shortened the HTML it takes to write by using an array with all the employee names. This makes it so if you need to add or remove an employee, it is much easier - all you do is remove or add it directly to the list and the for each loop creates the table row for you. This uses .each() similar to the method above, but utilizes the time type input you are using to do the math.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/arcxdff2/10/

JS

```
$(function() {
  var employees = ['Greg Weiland', 'Alicia Hawly', 'Charlen Connoly', 'Dakota Giles', 'Donovan Cole', 'Robert Hill', 'Douglas Spirs', 'Casey Green', 'Jared Peterson', 'Elizabeth P', 'Carl Mark', 'Carma J.', 'Ike J.', 'Elias H.'];

  //This for each loop will write the employee names in the array above into their own rows
  for (i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
    $('#footer').after('<tr class="rowEmployee"><th>' + employees[i] +
      '</th><td><input class="Time1" type="time"></td>' +
      '<td><input class="Time2" type="time">' +
      '</td><td><input class="Hours"></td></tr>')
  }

  $('#btnSubmit').on('click', function() {
    $('.rowEmployee').each(function() {
      var time1 = $('.Time1', this).val().split(':');
      var time2 = $('.Time2', this).val().split(':');
      //The following calculations turn minutes into a fraction to make the math easier
      var hoursWorked1 = parseInt(time1[0]) + ((parseInt(time1[1]) == 0) ? 0 : (parseInt(time1[1]) / 60));
      var hoursWorked2 = parseInt(time2[0]) + ((parseInt(time2[1]) == 0) ? 0 : (parseInt(time2[1]) / 60));
      //Here is your difference in hours calculation below
      var diff = hoursWorked2 - hoursWorked1;
      //Finally, write the total hours worked to the textbox, rounding to nearest hundredth
      $('.Hours', this).val(Math.round(diff*100)/100);
    });
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<table id="actual" cellspacing="0px">
  <tr id='header'>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Start Time</th>
    <th>End Time</th>
    <th>
      Total Time
      <br/> Worked
    </th>
  </tr>
  <!-- Add the ID of footer so the JS knows where to append the rows containing employee names -->
  <tr id="footer">
    <td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4" align="center">
      <button id='btnSubmit'>Submit</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The jsfiddle seems to be working but I had a few questions regarding the jquery and the array function. First is: is there a way to limit the output of the calculation to only 2 decimal places (as most hours are calculated as 'XX.XX'; and second: is there a way to build the table in the reverse order, or would I have to enter the names in the opposite order as I want them to appear on the table?

Comment: I just updated this not too long ago as I noticed it was writing them in reverse order. It is fixed now

Comment: Also for the rounding, yes you can. I have updated the fiddle again for that

Comment: Thank you. Although the code is a little hard to follow trying to figure out how you got it to work, due mostly to me being tired and a little distracted, it is working the way I would like it to. The next thing I would need to figure out how to add would be the "Scheduled" side of things but I am sure that I can figure out how to "tweak" the function so that it works in the second section as well. Once again, thank you

Comment: If you have any questions about the code, feel free to ask. I added in some comments to explain things.

Comment: Thank you for adding the comments. This will deffinently make it a little easier to read/understand while still very tired.

Comment: I added even more detailed comments inside the fiddle that will walk you through it. Have a good weekend!

Comment: I have plugged this function into my coding and added the needed bits for a "Scheduled" section, but I am now running into a little snag when it comes to calculating across midnight for Night shift. All information that I have been able to research on this subject points to needing to add a date stamp. I was wondering if you knew of a way to calculate hours across midnight without use of date stamps?

Comment: @Dragonman86 I'm not near a computer so I can't write code atm, but if you know it will always be across midnight do something like 12 - (shift start - shift end). For example, clock in at 10 pm and clock out at 2 am. So 12 - (10 - 2). 12- 8 = 4.

Comment: This is very rough because I tried to do it on a tablet, but here is what I am thinking. I will update it and get it working later when I am near a computer unless you understand where I am headed with it and get it working before. https://jsfiddle.net/arcxdff2/11/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108720/discussion-between-dragonman86-and-wizloc).

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this : (It's just an idea but it's working for the two first rows)

https://jsfiddle.net/6ob8q5z9/1/

```
$(function() {
    function calculate() {
        $("tr").each(function(i, el) {
            if ($(this).find(".Time1").length > 0) {         
                var time1 = $(this).find(".Time1").val().split(':'),
                    time2 = $(this).find(".Time2").val().split(':');
                var hours1 = parseInt(time1[0], 10),
                    hours2 = parseInt(time2[0], 10),
                    mins1 = parseInt(time1[1], 10),
                    mins2 = parseInt(time2[1], 10);
                var hours = hours2 - hours1,
                    mins = 0;
                if (hours < 0) hours = 24 + hours;
                if (mins2 >= mins1) {
                    mins = mins2 - mins1;
                } else {
                    mins = (mins2 + 60) - mins1;
                    hours--;
                }
                mins = mins / 60; // take percentage in 60
                hours += mins;
                hours = hours.toFixed(2);
                $(this).find(".Hours").val(hours);
            }
        });
    }
    $(".Time1,.Time2").change(calculate);
    calculate();
});
```

Comment: why not `$("tr").each(` here or perhaps better `$('#actual").find("tr").each(` to limit the selection

Comment: Thank you, this does seem to be working the way that I would like it to. Although I am liking the approach of wizloc from above as it reduces the total number of code lines I will need to maintain.